# Chaining tasks in Celery that have different inputs

Tags: python, celery

I have three celery tasks:

- Task 1: Given a directory, find and return a list of files
- Task 2: Given a file, determine if the file needs to be processed
- Task 3: Given a file that needs to be processed, process file

With the goal of all of this running asynchronously.

I'd like to chain these tasks together, but I don't believe I can as each task has different inputs... Correct?

This seems consistent with the chains documentation: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains

If I wanted to kick off Celery tasks using the output of the previous job as an input on the next one, how would I do that?